# Recursion - Python, return value question

Tags: python, recursion, stack

I realize that this may sound like a silly question, but the last time I programmed it was in assembler so my thinking may be off:

A recursive function as so:

```
def fac(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fac(n - 1)
```

Why is it that when the function reaches n == 0 that it does not return 1 but rather the answer which is the factorial. I am thinking something like in assembler it would be when n == 0:

```
mov eax, 1
ret
```

Why does the code above work, I suppose python returns the last value on the stack before that condition ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Think about like this, for `fac(5)` for example:

```
return 5 * fac(4)
           return 4 * fac(3)
                      return 3 * fac(2)
                                 return 2 * fac(1)
                                            return 1 * fac(0)
                                                       1
```

So `1` will be the *first* returned value but it will be returned to `fac(1)` and `fac(1)` will be returned to `fac(2)` and so on.

Comment: +1: And remember, the return value for "the function" isn't the return value for the entire expression, which involves many multiplies and function calls.  It's all about the "call stack" and the context in which the function is evaluated.

Comment: Thank you, that was a basic thing to miss. But I was thinking it was the other way round which was my mistake, this makes perfect sense now, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It **does** return 1 when n == 0. That return value is popped off the stack from the calling site, which was the invocation at `n * fac(n - 1)`. That `1` is multiplied by `n` and returned, etc.

Comment: Yes but lets say n == 4, it would still iterate and decrement a counter untill it reaches the end of the line, which in my logic would be when n == 0, ie, no more numbers left to multiply. Perhaps im confusing something very basic here, but I didnt find any explanation of how Python does recursion. I could do this function also with a do while loop, and then it would be more clear. But as its written now I just cant follow the logic, hope that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

If you call fac(0) it will return 1 (not 0, but I suppose that's just a typo in your question). If you call fac(1), it will go in the else clause, and there it will call `fac(0)`. This will return 1. It will then calculate n*1, which is 1, and return that. If you call `fac(2)` it will also go in the else clause, where it will call `fac(1)` which as mentioned above will return 1, so `n*fac(n-1)` will be 2 and that's the return value of `fac(2)`. And so on. I hope that explained it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's being implicitely returned - when n=0, the function is entering the if statement, and returning 1 directly from the `return 1` statement.
However, this isn't the point at which the "answer which is the factorial" is returned to the user.  Instead, it may be returning this value to the
*calling* function invoked by fac(1), which in the middle of the `n * fac(n - 1)` branch.  Thus it will take the "1" returned and return `n*1`, which is 1 to **it's** caller.  If that's fac(2), it'll return `n * 1`, or 2 to **it's** caller and so on.

Thus fac(5) gets translated like:

```
fac(5) = 5 * fac(4) = 5 * (4 * fac(3) = 5 * (4* (3 * fac(2)) = 5 * (4* (3 * (2 * fac(1)) = 5 * (4* (3 * (2 * (1 * fac(0)) = 5*4*3*2*1*1
```

Only after the 1 value gets returned through each upper layer does it get back to the first caller, and the multiplication at each stage gives you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

James, when the final call to your function (when n==0) returns it's just one of several instances of fac(n) on the call stack. If you say print(fac(4)), the stack is essentially:

```
fac(0)
fac(1)
fac(2)
fac(3)
fac(4)
print()
```

The final call to fac(0) appropriately returns 1, however in Python you've requested the return value of the first call to fac(n), fac(4).

Don't think of it as a loop wherein 'ret' will break out, the return simply concludes one of several pending executions.